# Store dataprovider parameters as array in test method in testng

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am writing excel data to an array and returning the same via @dataprovider. Code looks something like this-

```
for(i=0;i<numrow+1;i++){
      for (j=0;j<numcol;j++ ){
          if(xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j)!=null){
              xldata[i][j]=xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString();
          }
          else{
              xldata[i][j]="";
          }
      }
}

return xldata;
```

The excel I am reading has about 40 columns and I want to write the same to an array in my @test method. So I tried using below code in my @test method to read the data provided by @dataprovider

```
@Test(dataProvider = "name")
public void mymethod(String[] fromxl) {
 //code
}
```

But somehow array isn't recognized as an array and I am getting error saying - dataprovider has 40 parameters, but test method accepts only 1.
Now if I change the array to 40 different parameters in my test method (sample code below), it seems to be working. But I don't want to do this as this is cumbersome. Any reason why I can't make the array to work in my test method ? Appreciate any help/pointers on this

```
@Test(dataProvider = "name")
public void mymethod(String data1, .. , String data40) {
 //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass in an array as a parameter to a test you just need to wrap it in the `Object[][]` used by the `DataProvider`.  Something like this should do what you want:

```java
private String[] buildSingleDimensionArray() {
    String[] result = new String[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = "element" + i;
    }
    return result;
}

@DataProvider(name = "arrayBuilder")
public Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] { { buildSingleDimensionArray() }, };

}

@Test(dataProvider = "arrayBuilder")
public void theTest(String[] inputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do I read all rows from an excel ? As in, say there are 10 rows and 40 columns, I need to return all this from dataprovider in single return statement, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Your test needs just one argument - the string array.  So your xldata should return a single argument in form of string array.

```
for(i=0;i<numrow+1;i++){

      for (j=0;j<numcol;j++ ){
          if(xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j)!=null){
          //Build fresh array here instead of writing directly to return
               freshArr[j] = ...
          }
          else{
              freshArr[0] = "" ;
          }
//once all columns are read, set that to the return array
          xldata[i][0] = freshArr;
      }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I don' see how different this is than what I am doing in my code. What am I missing ? :|

Comment: When you say this doesn't work. .what do you mean..exception? Error?   Elaborate

Comment: I meant,this doesn't solve the original issue mentioned in post. I get the same exception that dataprovider has 40 parameters, but test method accepts only 1

Comment: Post your new code - i had given a hint to solve the problem.  Want to see what you have done.  I am pretty sure this would work.  The difference is in the way the multi dimensional array is being created.  We are setting just the 0th ele..i.e. only one arg to test

Comment: Hi, this does work, sorry about that. I had to declare freshArr inside first for loop such that a new reference is created for each row of excel. So it does work for now, probably not the most efficient way, but will figure that later. I will post the full code in answers. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -

```
for(i=0;i<numrow;i++){
  String[] newArray=new String[numcol]; 
  for (j=0;j<numcol;j++ ){
      if(xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j)!=null){
          XSSFCell cellval=xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j);
          cellval.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
          newArray[j] = cellval.toString();
      }
      else{
          newArray[j] = "";
      }
  }
  xldata[i][0] = newArray;  
}
return xldata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are still looking for an answer, then here is the solution:
First of all not sure what your excel data spreadsheet looks like, but your for loop should say something like this...

```
for(i=0;i<numrow+1;i++){
      for (j=0;j<numcol;j++ ){
          if(xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j)!=null){
              xldata[I][j]=xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
      }
      else{
          xldata[i][j]="";
      }
  }
}

return xldata;
```

And when you have the xldata[I][j], you need to return an object of two dimensional from this method...like "return xldata" and your method should have String[][] and the return type.
ex: something like this

```
public String[][] readExcelData(String filename, String sheetName, String tableName){
...
...
...
for(i=0;i<numrow+1;i++){
      for (j=0;j<numcol;j++ ){
      if(xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j)!=null){
          xldata[i][j]=xlsh.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
      }
      else{
          xldata[i][j]="";
      }
  }
}

return xldata;

}
```

Your test method also should expect the same row and column data..something like this depending on what data you are getting from the spreadsheet, if may be 2 parameters or more as well...

```
Ex:
@Test(dataProvider = "name")
public void test1(String row, String col){
..
}
```

Try an implementation like this and hope it works!